# pattern to unlock thread and get variable in fast unlock

Tags: design-patterns, c++, pthreads

I have a thread that goes in a loop doing something like this

```
void thread()
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);

  for ( ; ; )
  {
    /** code **/
    {
      pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
      /** do_something **/
      pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    }

    if (exit)
      return;
  }
}
```

where **exit** will be updated in a different thread to true if needed. My problem is that this works fine when **do_something** takes some time, but if it doesn't the other thread never gets the mutex back. Or it takes too long to do so.

What is the correct pattern in a situation like this?

Comment: I'm curious why you aren't using `std::thread` pthreads are awful and don't work across platforms

Comment: its a requirenment of the system I'm working on. std::thread are available on c++11 and I cannot assume that the compiler is c++11 compatible. Let's just say its not up to me. Otherwise yes, I would go with std::thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem here seems to be that this thread keeps the mutex locked by default, and only unlocks it for a limited period of time when it's sure it doesn't need to the mutex.

Normally, you want to do roughly the opposite: the mutex is unlocked by default, and only gets locked for a short period of time when absolutely necessary. Without knowing at least a little bit about the rest of the code, it's hard to be sure of the right way to do that though.

One possibility would be restructure the code so that only a single thread has to deal directly with the shared resources, and the other two threads each have a queue of requests they submit to that thread. That thread can then prioritize the requests, so both client threads get an equal chance to do their thing with the shared resources (or maybe not necessarily equal, but an appropriate amount for each).

As an aside, if you can't use C++11 threading classes, I'd at least consider writing rough analogs of them--a `mutex` class that calls `pthread_mutex_create` in its ctor, `pthread_mutex_destroy` in its dtor, and has a `lock` and `unlock` that call `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock` respectively.

Likewise, a `lock_guard` that's passed a mutex that it locks in its ctor, and unlocks in its dtor (and possibly a similar wrapper for condition variables, etc.) Bottom line: if you're starting from pthreads, you can write a pretty substantial subset of the standard library threading pretty quickly and easily.

Both of these are pretty trivial, and simplify the rest of the code enough that the time to develop them will be repaid quite quickly. In addition, they'll get you things like exception safety that are *much* more difficult to implement in most other ways.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have access to all C++11 functionality. I left that part out of the question because it did not seem important. The code is large, and it already took me quite a while to find this block which actually seldon happens. I was just out of ideas about how to approach the issue. This made my brain click: "Normally, you want to do roughly the opposite: the mutex is unlocked by default, and only gets locked for a short period of time when absolutely necessary."

Answer (score 4):

In this function, you lock mutex and keep it locked except for a tiny part, where you `do_something`, letting the other threads aquire the mutex, before waiting to re-lock it.

**What's wrong ?**

1. When `exit` is true, the thread finishes, leaving `mutex` locked and  blocking all the other threads waiting to acquire it.  Maybe it's on purpose, but for me, it looks rather suspicious (especially if you have some [`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) somewhere).
2. The function seems not exception safe either, for a similar reason:  should an exception occur in `/* code */`, would it cause `mutex` to remain locked, and your process stuck forever due to the other threads waiting for `mutex`.  `std::thread` offers [`lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) as a wrapper that makes sure according to the [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) principle that the lock is removed if the guard would be destroyed for example due to stack unwinding.
3. Depending on `do_something`,  the other threads waiting to acquire `mutex` might [starve](http://www.cs.kent.edu/~ruttan/sysprog/lectures/multi-thread/multi-thread.html#thread_mutex_starvation_deadlock) (e.g. no other thread get an opportunity to acquire the lock,  or always the same get the lock at the expense of all the others, etc...).

**How to get it right ?**

It's not easy with the litle we know to give you the best advice.  However, at first sight, it seems that you could think of using another synchronization mechanism, the condition variables. These exist as [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) if you use the standard threads.  But they exist also for pthreads, as explained in detail [in this article](http://www.cs.kent.edu/~ruttan/sysprog/lectures/multi-thread/multi-thread.html#thread_condvar).

Long story short, condition variables do something similar to your code:  several threads are waiting with [`pthread_cond_wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html) for an event that is advertised using a condition variable.  A thread wakes up the waiting threads with [`pthread_cond_broadcast()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_broadcast.html) or [`pthread_cond_signal()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_broadcast.html). One of the thread gets control with the  locked mutex.